# How to integrate Microsoft chatbot to existing asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, botframework, chatbot

I have created chatbot demo application from article http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-a-simple-bot-application-using-microsoft-bot-framew/

Now I just want to integrate this chat bot to my existing asp.net web application, for this I have created a asp.net website and published it on file system locally

can anyone please tell how to integrate this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a prebuilt solution for this known as the Webchat control. It is an open source project which offers customization.  You can also put it on you website just as an iFrame if you would rather go that route.  Take a look at the readme on the [repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) to get started.  there is also [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat) that tells you how to include webchat as a channel in your bot registration.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, sorry.  Please read the documentation I linked